# horizontal lines on laptop display

Tags: laptop, display, laptop-display

This laptop is not even 1 month old. Why am I seeing horizontal lines on the display? Is it normal?
I'm using it for more than 6 hours a day. 
The gray horizontal line shows up immediately after booting up. So I think this is not software related.
How do I solve this problem?
If you need more details just feel free to ask, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds quite like a GPU problem.
To check this is the case plug in an external monitor. If this has the same problems then the problem is the graphics chip / card. The laptop should still be in warranty if only 1 month old. They should repair it free of charge for you.

Comment: what might have caused it?Is it me using this laptop for more than 6 hours a day?

Comment: If you have dropped it on the floor, it could be your fault, but it's not your fault if you have simply used the laptop normally. Sometimes electronic components fail, and if they do, that often happens very early. It's not like mechanical parts that wear out; electronics either fail early, or they work "forever".

Answer (score 4):

it could also be a problem with the display, not necessarily the graphics card.
In either case, you should bring it back to the store for a warranty replacement.

Comment: Thats why you plug in the external display. To rule out the laptops screen

Comment: Agree; and if the image on the external monitor is okay, then you know it's the laptop's display. That's all I meant.